# Can we call truncate command in trigger command using sql server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, truncate

Can we possible to call truncate command inside trigger using sql server?

Comment: Surely as quick to try it as post a question

Comment: [Yes, you can.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf8758359d8b6a5212a0c78d653d1d79) Better question is why would you want to...

Comment: @Charlieface You can delete faster with truncate. As an example to delete history in a tracking table, everytime one row is added to a dba table to oversee who is working... Do not forget that TRUNCATE is an operation that does'nt fire the trigger DELETE... Whch can be interesting for certain use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRUNCATE command is a transactional command and all the pages deleted will be writed into the transaction log. And because the trigger code is envolved in a transaction, you can ROLLBACK or COMMIT the implicit transaction into the trigger code (COMMIT is not a good practice into trigger code).

So, yes, you can !